# Snail climbing a tree stump

Tags: logical-deduction

A snail is slowly climbing a tree stump. The stump height is 100 cm.

At day, the snail manages to climb 20 cm upwards.

At night, while sleeping, the snail slips 10 cm downwards.

**After how many days will the snail reach the top of the tree stump?**

Comment: 4 day if he sleep upside down

Comment: This is such a classic puzzle, I thought this must be a duplicate, but I can't find earlier mentions. It is usually framed as a snail in a well, not on a tree stump.

Comment: There is an earlier one -- https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-long-does-it-take-for-the-snail-to-get-out-of-the-well -- but it was deleted for being a simple mathematics problem rather than a puzzle. (FWIW, I think it *is* a puzzle, albeit one both very easy and very well known.)

Comment: @Kepotx : I remembered this from school, loong time ago. I could not find it, and thought it would fit here :)

Comment: A sentiment expressed in a comment on the now-deleted question @Gareth mentioned points out that while there is a twist to this question that makes it something beyond a mere math problem, "that twist is so trivial I'm not sure you can really call this a good puzzle".  I'm personally inclined to agree; there's not enough *puzzle* here for me.

Comment: I am also not sure you can really call this a *good* puzzle. But to my mind it is certainly *a* puzzle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The snail will reach the top after

> 9 days.

This is because

> the snail essentially climbs 10 cm per day. After 8 days (and nights), it is at a height of 80 cm. The day after, it climbs the remaining 20 cm to the top and doesn't slip down anymore.

Another way to see why this is the solution<sup>1</sup>, is to

1. > see that the snail climbs to a height of 20 cm in the first day.
2. > After the first night (slipping down 10 cm) and second day (climbing 20 cm), it has climbed 10 cm to reach a height of 30 cm.
3. > Every following night + day will help the snail climb 10 cm further: after the third day, it has reached a height of 40 cm, after the fourth day it reached 50 cm, et cetera.
4. > Thus, after the ninth day it reaches 100 cm, the height of the tree stump.

________
<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to [Jaap Scherphuis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20814/jaap-scherphuis) for [suggesting](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66130/snail-climbing-a-tree-stump/66131?noredirect=1#comment199751_66131) this way of explaining the solution.</sub>

Comment: Your solution looks at it as (day+night)+(day+night)+(day+night)+...+(day+night)+day. I find the explanation a bit cleaner if you look at it as day+(night+day)+(night+day)+..., so that you are always looking at the peaks of where the snail gets to. It completely takes the 'twist' out of the solution.

Comment: Thank you @Jaap! I have edited that way of explaining the solution into my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

> 9 Days

Explanation:

> Day 1:- Ascent:20 Descent:10            Total:10
>  Day 2:- Ascent:20 Descent:10            Total:20
>  Day 3:- Ascent:20 Descent:10            Total:30
>  Day 4:- Ascent:20 Descent:10            Total:40
>  Day 5:- Ascent:20 Descent:10            Total:50
>  Day 6:- Ascent:20 Descent:10            Total:60
>  Day 7:- Ascent:20 Descent:10            Total:70
>  Day 8:- Ascent:20 Descent:10            Total:80
>  Day 9:- Ascent:20 Descent:NOT REQUIRED  Total:100

Comment: Hello and welcome to Puzzling.SE! Good answer (even if it was already discover). Usually, answer are embed in spoiler tags, using ">!" so you can't see the answer by mistake

Comment: Also correct, make a graph! :P